# Is the first and second convolution equivalent

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have the first .prototxt of a convolution as follows:

```
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    axis: 1
    num_output: 32
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    kernel_size: 3
    kernel_size: 3
    engine: CAFFE
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      std: 0
    }     
  }
}
```

And the second .prototxt of a convolution as follows:

```
layer {
  name: "conv1"
  type: "Convolution"
  bottom: "data"
  top: "conv1"
  convolution_param {
    num_output: 32
    pad: 1
    kernel_size: 3
    engine: CAFFE
    weight_filler {
      type: "gaussian"
      std: 0.01
    }
    bias_filler {
      type: "constant"
      std: 0
    }     
  }
}
```

The different between first and second convolution are the addition definition `axis=1` and three times `kernel_size: 3`. Is the first and second convolution equivalent? Given that the input data is 3D data.

Comment: you mean the input is 5D: batch-channel-z-x-y ?

Comment: Yes, actually the channel =1 for gray image.

Comment: axis=1 means the channel axis is 1 and that all dimensions after that are your spatial dimensions

Comment: So what is happen when I ignore it. Because I did not see the setting.

Comment: look at caffe.proto for the default value

Comment: Yes. The default values is one `optional int32 axis = 2 [default = 1];`. Hence, I think we can ignore it. How about three times defines kernel_size? I think caffe can know and adjust it based on the input data

Comment: so I guess the two are the same